# How to change react-bootstrap navbar-toggler-icon button and button color

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-bootstrap

I am trying to change the react-bootstrap navbar-toggler-icon to the font-awesome icon and also change the icon color.

Image for details:

[image]

Comment: It would be good if someone could improve the answer to include how to change the icon when the menu has been exspanded

Answer (score 19):

Find the Navbar.Toggle or directly Toggle (how it was imported, you'll see) in related navbar section.

```
<Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
```

As default and basicly it looks like this. Bootstrap's default is like what you see currently.

```
<Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav"> <YOUR ICON /> </Navbar.Toggle>
```

Just add icon as a children inside Navbar.Toggle then you can style whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using bootstrap icons, Here is my simple solution in 2021, replace this code with your favorite icon class.

[Boostrap icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/)

```
<Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav">
  {/* Replace your icon here */}
  <i class="bi bi-gear"></i>
</Navbar.Toggle>
```

Answer (score 0):

just go to your custom css file and add background image for .navbar-toggler-icon
example

```
.navbar-toggler-icon{
background-image:url('../../resources/Images/Home/navicon2.png') !important;
```

}